# Decrypting with RSA Private Key

Tags: java, android, encryption

So I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt a string using RSA public and private keys. It encrypts fine, but whenever I attempt to decrypt the encrypted string I get a very odd output. For example, "hello" decrypts to:

> �]t1��#Z�-�-p���ԏh2�5�~��E'����bh��~�-I�����t�k�>�����+
>   v���?NA��y�[@���jp!2p�X@oZ$٥�@&�v���=�A��e�A�m��;@d<"&}���  ���}r�q5U������?�J�c���`�Db�A�!`�{�w|�IE�Ì魈S��]`�'����88��%������   ��O.N:S`�E�J0�4�l�3�ϓn3��{.�

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my decrypting algorithm or if it has to do with converting the decrypted bytes into a string (or something along those lines).

Here's the decryption method:

```
public String decryptString(PrivateKey key, String string) {
    try {

        pubDecryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(string.getBytes());
        byte[] unencryptedByteArray = pubDecryptCipher.doFinal(decodedBytes);
        return new String(unencryptedByteArray, "UTF8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Encryption:

```
public String encryptString(PublicKey key, String string) {
    try {
        pubEncryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] eba = pubEncryptCipher.doFinal(string.getBytes("UTF8"));
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(eba);

        return encodedBytes.toString();

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Decrypted string in hex:

```
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
```

And by string algorithm do you mean:

```
pubEncryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
pubDecryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

?

Comment: Could you show us the encryption code, the algorithm string and the result *in hexadecimals*? It looks like you are using `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` which is always the incorrect algorithm string; the padding mode is an important part of RSA encryption/decryption.

Comment: @owlstead alright updated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `encodedBytes.toString()` does not do what you expect it to do. You need to do `new String(encodedBytes, StandardCharsets.ASCII);` instead. Or `new String(encodedBytes, Charset.forName("ASCII"));` before Java SE 1.7 compatible code.

You should always indicate the padding mode; please use e.g. `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` instead of `"RSA"`.

Comment: Could you check which of the functions above work on android (for a specific version you are working with)?

Comment: Adding any sort of padding gives me a different error. For `PCKS1Padding` it gives me `...BadPaddingException:...RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02`. Also `new String(encodedBytes, Charset.ForName("ASCII")` didn't work.

Comment: That would also happen if your public key does not match the private key... Can you double check by comparing the modulus of both? Oh, and perform `decodeBase64` on the string, not on a byte array (can you imagine what happens if `getBytes()` returns UTF-16?).

Comment: Yep, the same. It's a simple app, I'm just generating a new key pair every time and then just using the public to encrypt and private to decrypt.

Comment: What is the result if you perform all the given hints?

Comment: When I try to encode the straight string, for whatever reason during runtime it gives me a `NoSuchMethodException` which doesn't make sense since I'm using commons-codec.1.8.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43068/discussion-between-owlstead-and-embattled-swag)